# Error while Updating .mdf database

Tags: sql, sql-server, mdf, server-explorer

Following errors occurred while updating an **.mdf** database, it was working fine but before editing the Column Names of few tables.
(I am using **Server Explorer** of **Visual Studio 2013**.)

Update cannot proceed due to validation errors.
Please correct the following errors and try again.

SQL72015 :: The table [dbo].[Customer] is being dropped and re-created since all non-computed columns within the table have been redefined.

SQL72031 :: This deployment may encounter errors during execution because changes to [dbo].[Product].[ProductID] are blocked by [dbo].[Product]'s dependency in the target database.

SQL72031 :: This deployment may encounter errors during execution because changes to [dbo].[Transaction].[TransactionID] are blocked by [dbo].[Transaction]'s dependency in the target database.

SQL72031 :: This deployment may encounter errors during execution because changes to [dbo].[Purchase].[TransactionID] are blocked by [dbo].[Purchase]'s dependency in the target database.

SQL72031 :: This deployment may encounter errors during execution because changes to [dbo].[Sales].[TransactionID] are blocked by [dbo].[Sales]'s dependency in the target database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Go to `Tools` menu -> `Options` -> `Database Tools` -> `Table and Database Designers` ( -> Table and Diagram Options) -> **Untick/Unselect** `Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation`.

This is as of VS2010, but it should not be much different in VS2013.

Comment: Making changes to table drops the table and then recreates it. So you have to remove the dependency first, then make changes to the db. You can do it by dropping all kinds of constraints, foreign keys, relations related to the table you are modifying.

Comment: Have you tried to modify db in SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 1):

[1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607113/cannot-deploy-database-from-tfs) To make these changes, either perform them manually using SQL Server Management Studio or use Visual Studio Professional (or above) to perform a Schema Compare and select the option to ignore the possibility of data loss.

[2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607113/cannot-deploy-database-from-tfs) The TSD01234 error is also caused by having the "Verify Deployment" setting checked in your project's .sqlDeployment file (it is the last one under "advanced options").

[3.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607113/cannot-deploy-database-from-tfs) Explicitly name the columns in the view. Deployment doesn't like wildcards.

Comment: what are the dangers in setting "Verify Deployment" off? can it cause data loss?